# Javascript Input Validation Using Object

Tags: javascript

Has anyone ever used input validation by passing a created object to a function?  See my code.

```
var inputValidation =
{
    validationEmployeeName: "Please Enter Your Name",
    validationOdomReading: "Please Enter A Valid Number",
    validationEndReading: "The Ending Odometer Reading Must be >= Beginning",
    validationDaysUsed: "Please Enter The Number of Days Car Used",
    validateEmployeeName: inputData.elements["txtEmployeeName"].value,
    validateBegOdomReading: parseFloat(inputData.elements["txtBegOdomReading"].value),
    validateEndOdomReading: parseFloat(inputData.elements["txtEndOdomReading"].value),
    validateDaysCarUsed: parseFloat(inputData.elements["txtDaysCarUsed"].value)
};

//Input Validation

validData = checkValidation(inputValidation);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're in stuck with.

Comment: I am actually not stuck, the program works.  I was just wondering if it is good coding to place the validations into one object and pass that object to the function that does the checking for valid data.  I am actually new to javascript.

Comment: Nope, it does not look like a good design

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning so that I may improve my future code?

Comment: You are just mixing everything together. Just google for validation libraries

Comment: This is a straight javascript program.  I would rather not rely on someone else's work.  I looked at those libraries, and if I looked correctly, the code is already written for you, you just fill in the properties, correct?  I am basically taking a form validation object oriented approach.

Comment: so if you think that it's fine and you don't agree with other people's opinion - what your "question" is about then?

Comment: I was just wanting to know if anyone else has taken this approach to input validation.

Comment: There is no any "approach" here. Just an object with values.